# Plot elements of two arrays in Bash

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have two arrays "bitrates" and "psnr". I want to write a bash script to plot it.

```
bitrates=(1 2 3 4 5)
```

`psnrArray=()`
 psnr array is filled dynamically.

```
{ echo "${bitrates[*]}"; echo "${psnrArray[*]}"; } >Data
```

Comment: So, you wanna do something, you do it, and now you write about it on SO.  Thanks for sharing!  But where is your question?

Comment: Must-haves of all questions:  ① What did you do?  ② What did you expect to observe?  ③ What did you observe instead?

Comment: How to plot it using gnuplot?. And also the data are in rows. I think it should be in columns.

Comment: I want a plot in which data from bitrates array will be in x axis and data from psnrarrays will be in y-axis.

Answer (score 2):

Creating your data file can be done like this:

```
x=(1 2 3 4)
y=(5 6 7 8)
for ((i=0; i<${#x[@]}; i++))
do
  echo "${x[$i]}" "${y[$i]}"
done > data
```

Plotting using Gnuplot:

```
gnuplot -p -e "plot 'data' with lp"
```

Comment: Less readable but shorter for creating the data file would be sth like: `paste <(printf "%d\n" "${x[@]}") <(printf "%d\n" "${y[@]}") > data`.